# TeamCity not seeing changes when building from deleted/recreated branch in SVN

Tags: svn, teamcity

I've set up Teamcity 5.1.4 to do dev CI builds against the trunk in our SVN repository.  Then I also set up a "QA" build that points to a "QA" branch in the svn repository too.  Rather than deal with ugly merges, we delete the QA branch and just create a new branch from the head on trunk.

But when we do this, Teamcity doesn't see any changes in the files.  I have to remove my teamcity VCS root for that project and create it again.  I've tried forcing a clean build on the project, but nothing other than removing the current VCS root for the project and creating a new one seems to help.

Is there an easier way to get it to build these, forcing it to get the full checkout from SVN?

Answer (score 0):

How many repositories do you have set up? Do you have a repository for trunk and a repository for the QA branch?

If you do you should consider having a single repository that is shared between your projects and use checkout rules to identify which branch to use, see this [example](http://unstableterrain.wordpress.com/2009/10/14/configuring-teamcity-for-subversion/). This may help your current situation but it will also make it easier to label and allow you to share a template between your two builds.

Comment: I have a single repo -- I just want a "QA Build" that runs against a tag in that repository.  The problem is that if I delete the /tags/QA folder in the repository and recreate it from the HEAD, TeamCity doesn't actually see the changes in that tag.  Maybe my problem is that I'm using a VCS root that's pointed to the TAG instead of to the top of the repo.

Comment: @Jake - I would try using the single repository that points to the top as mentioned in the linked article and use the check out rules.

Comment: Ok, I reworked all my projects to us a single VCS root at the top level of my repository, and added checkout rules to each project so they'd get the files needed.  So DevBuild uses a rule to get /trunk, but QA build uses a rule to get /tags/QA.  Unfortunately this did not seem to make any difference.  If I delete /tags/QA from the repo and create a new tag from the trunk, TeamCity does NOT see that the tag has been updated and refuses to get the latest source.

Comment: @Jake - I was talking to my colleague and he thinks that a branch may be associated with a guid that TeamCity holds onto. When you delete the branch and recreate it a new guid is created. Can you just purge the branch and re-add the data?